# Riemannian tensor and Levi Civita connection

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

For a riemannian metric $g$ consider the following tensor $T_{rstu}=k(x)g_{rt}g_{su}-k(x)g_{st}g_{ru}$. Which condition has to satisfy $k$ if we want the tensor $T$ to be the Riemann tensor of a Levi-Civita connection?

any suggestions? thanks

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The Riemann tensor is given by a linear combination of the derivatives of the metric, as you can see in this post: [Riemann tensor in terms of the metric tensor](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628863/riemann-tensor-in-terms-of-the-metric-tensor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Riemannian curvature tensor takes this form, then at any given point all the sectional curvatures are equal. Thus if $n>2$ then [Schur's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_lemma_(from_Riemannian_geometry)) tells us that the sectional curvature is in fact constant; i.e. $k$ must be constant. If $n=2$ then this is the problem of prescribed Gauss curvature, which you should be able to find many papers about.