# Does the sign of curvature remain constant under the sum of their metrics?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Does the sign of curvature remain constant under the sum of their metrics over a fixed manifold? e.g. If $(M,g_1)$ and $(M,g_2)$ are closed Riemannian manifolds of positive curvature then $(M,g_1+g_2)$ is also of positive curvature?

**Update: Q2:** What if we weaken the problem by allowing manifolds having boundary?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but the analogous question for positive scalar curvature metrics is false, see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2682383/39599).

Comment: So, My question and what you linked are interesting and ongoing problems?

Comment: I wouldn't say so. I'm pretty sure very few properties of metrics are closed under addition. I think the answer to your question is no.

Comment: It's also false for *constant* positive curvature metrics. This follows from the negative answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/304059/21564).

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: Why negative answer to linked post gives a negative answer to my question for constant positive sec curvature metrics?

Comment: If the sum of constant positive sectional curvature metrics had constant positive sectional curvature, then for any quotient of $S^n/\Gamma$, one could find a constant positive sectional curvature metric on $S^n$ which descends to the quotient (namely $\sum_{\gamma\in\Gamma}\gamma^*g_{\text{round}}$). However, there are quotients of $S^n$ which do not admit such metrics.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: So you claim that the result may not of _constant_ positive curvature and it may or may not have of positive curvature. Yes?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**  As C.F.G. noted, I had originally answered different but related question.  So, let me answer the actual question asked with a No: the sum of two positively curved metrics can have negative curvature.  I'll construct an example below.

To do so, consider $S^3$ with a metric $g_\lambda$ making it a [Berger Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berger%27s_sphere).  Recall that this is obtained by beginning with the usual round metric $g_0$ and scaling it in the direction of the Hopf fibers.  More precisely, given any vectors $v,w\in T_p S^3$, we define $g_\lambda(v,w) = g_0(v,w) + \lambda g_0(v',w')$ where $v'$ is the $g_0$-projection of $v$ to the tangent space of the Hopf circle through $p$, and likewise for $w'$.

It is known that the resulting metric $g_\lambda$ is positive curved iff $-1<\lambda < 1/3$.  (If $\lambda \leq -1$, then $g_\lambda(v,v) \leq 0$ for all $v$ tangent to a Hopf circle, so we don't even get a metric in this case).

Pick any $\lambda$ strictly between $0$ and $1/3$.

Now, consider the metric $g:=g_{\lambda} + t g_0$ on $S^3$.  For any $t > 0$, this is a sum of positively curved metrics.  However, I claim that for any $t$ with $0< t < 3 \lambda -1$, that $g$ has negative curvature planes.

To see this, note that \begin{align*} g(v,w) &= g_\lambda(v,w) + t g_0(v,w)\\ &= (1+t) g_0(v,w) + \lambda g_0(v',w'),\end{align*} so $$\frac{1}{1+t} g(v,w) = g_0(v,w) + \frac{\lambda}{1+t} g_0(v',w')$$ is a Berger metric $g_{\lambda/(1+t)}$.  Since scaling doesn't change the sign of curvature, it follows that if we can show that $\lambda/(1+t) > \frac{1}{3}$, we are done.  Since $t< 3 \lambda - 1$, we find $\lambda/(1+t) > \lambda/(1 + 3\lambda - 1) = \frac{1}{3}.$

**End edit - the old answer is left below**

**Proposition**:  There is a positive curved metric $g_b$

No, the sum of metrics of fixed signed curvature is, in general, not of the same sign.

**Proposition**:  If the sum of any two positively curved metrics is positively curved, then every closed manifold of dimension $2$ or more admits a metric of positive curvature.

**Proof**:  First, if $g$ is a metric with positive curvature, then $\lambda g$ is for any positive $\lambda$.  Also, an easy induction argument shows that the hypothesis imply that any finite sum of positively curved metrics is positively curved.

Now, given any closed manifold $M^n$, compactness allows us to cover $M$ by a finite collection of open sets $U_1,..., U_k$, each diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the property that their closures $\overline{U_i}$ are contained in open sets $V_i$ which are also diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Let $\lambda_i$ be a partition of unity supported on $\overline{U}_i$.

Since $n\geq 2$, each $V_i$ admits a metric $g_i$ which is positively curved.  For example view $\mathbb{R}^n$ as the complement of a point in $S^n$ then pull the induced metric back to $g_i$.

Now the metic $g = \sum \lambda_i g_i|_{U_i}$ is positively curved by the first paragraph.  $\square$

Of course, there are obstructions to admitting a positively curved metric.  So, a consequence of this is that the sum of positively curved metrics need not be positively curved.

Comment: Two remarks: 1.  I was purposely vague about what kind of curvature was intended.  The proof works for sectional, Ricci, and scalar and likely any other kind of curvature you can define.  2.  If you change "positive" to "zero", the last paragraph also works fine.  If you change "positive" to "negative", then there's a caveat - there are no obstructions to admitting a metric of negative scalar or Ricci curvature when $n\geq 3$, so this proof does not rule out the possibility that a sum of metrics of negative scalar curvature has negative scalar curvature if $n\geq 3$.

Comment: I don't know the answer to that.  My guess is that it depends on properties of $f$.

Comment: I read your answer again, but something is not along my main question: my assumption is "$g_1$ and $g_2$ are metrics on a fixed manifold $M$" but your argument is about $g = \sum \lambda_i g_i|_{U_i}$ where each $g_i$ is on different space $U_i$ and you cannot use the hypothesis I think. the correct replacement for your first para is this: "_The hypothesis imply that any finite sum of positively curved metrics on a fixed $M$ is positively curved on $M$._"

Comment: @C.F.G.:  Why can't you just take $M=U_1\cap U_2$?

Comment: In your answer? or in my post? If you meant my post, then that intersection is not closed I think.

Comment: Also each $U_i$ is not a closed manifold, so you cannot use the hypothesis.

Comment: I see the problem now.  I will think about a fix.

Comment: I think using curvature formula in terms of metric [see this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/628867/272127) one can derive $R=R_1+R_2$ and consequently $\sec=\sec_1+\sec_2$. Am I right?

Comment: @C.F.G:  No, $R = R_1 + R_2$ is not generally true.  The problem with using the formula in the post is that the definition of the coordinates used changes when you change the metric.  I've added an explicit counter example.

Comment: @Thanks, Now it is OK. Do you think Your old answer is valid for manifolds with boundary? but I have problem with still because that metrics $g_k$ are not on fixed base manifold say $U_i$.

Comment: @C.F.G:  What's stops you from using the new answer on the three disk embedded in $S^3$?

Comment: This is a quiz for me? :) The boundary of disk? or perhaps it admit a flat metric?

Comment: @C.F.G:  Sorry, no.  I don't know why I'm being so terse.  What I mean is, if you take $D^3$ embedded in the $S^3$ in my new answer, you have a manifold with boundary, together with metrics positive curved metrics whose sum is not positively curved.  Are you wanting to impose additional constraints on the metric on the boundary?

Comment: Oh, You meant this answer is not valid too? if so, lets to update question to add second part about boundary.

Comment: Why doesn't my new answer answer your new question, by restricting the metrics I use to an embedded $3$-disk?

Comment: Jason, sorry, your comment is a little ambiguous for me. You meant "do you know that why it doesn't ... (but I know its point)" or it is a direct question? (sorry for being confused)

Comment: I think it does. Doesn't?

Comment: I'm confused too!  I believe that my example on $S^3$ above, when restricted to any embedded $3$-manifold with boundary, is an answers to your second question.  However, I typically do not think about manifolds with boundary in the context of Riemannian geometry, so I may be missing something.  For example, do people usually only consider Riemannian metrics with some kind of special behavior at the boundary?  If so, then my answer may not work in that case.

Comment: Dear Jason Devito, Do you have a reference for "It is known that the resulting metric ..." part about Berger sphere? Your example absolutely answers my question. But still It is odd for me that intuitively why sum of two metrics of positive curvature, may not of positive curvature.

Comment: @C.F.G:  This example is in Petersen's text book Riemannian Geometry, section 4.4.3.  Looking at it, I see that my answer is slightly wrong:  instead of $-1 < \lambda < 1/3$ being the condition for positive sectional curvature, it's $0 < (1+\lambda)^2 < 4/3$.  (I forgot to square it).

Comment: Before of your usage of Berger spheres, I thought that Berger spheres is a simple example like sphere. But now I see it is a very nice, applicable and clever example. Thanks for bringing to my attention this example.

Comment: In Petersen's Book, p. 260 (3rd ed.) the bound is $[\varepsilon^2, 4-3\varepsilon^2]$. This is different from your bounds!!

Comment: @C.F.G:  Petersen is interested in what happens as $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$, so he assumes (after doing some work) that $\varepsilon < 1$, then gets the bound you quote.   But if $\varepsilon =1+\lambda>\sqrt{4/3},$ the same calculation  works, it's just that $4-3\varepsilon^2$ is negative, so curvature is bounded by $[4-3\varepsilon^2, \varepsilon^2]$.